# If cell is empty, make reference to another cell of other column in the same row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to do this in G column : If Cell 'G8' is Blank Then (=K8) for example. My difficulty is to make reference of same row in K of empty cell in G.

[image]

I've tryed to adapt this script but I get a shift at some point and I don't know why.

```
function updatewithformula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange()
  var source = sheet.getRange('G1:G13').getDisplayValues()
  var index = []
  for (var i = 1; i<source.length; i++){
    if (source[i][0] == ""){
      index.push(i+1) 
        }
  }
  index.push(range.getLastRow()+1)
  Logger.log(index)
  for(var i = 0;i<index.length-1;i++){
       var rangetomodify = sheet.getRange(index[i],7,1,1)
       var l = index[i+1]-index[i]-1
      rangetomodify.setFormulaR1C1("=R["+l+"]C[4]")
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another approach, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- About `I've tryed to adapt this script but I get a shift at some point and I don't know why.`, in your script, `"=R[" + l + "]C[4]"` is used with `var l = index[i + 1] - index[i] - 1`. In this case, when `l` is not 0, the other row is used. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In your script, I think that it is not required to use `var l = index[i + 1] - index[i] - 1`. When your script is simply modified, it becomes as follows.

  ```js
  function updatewithformula() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var source = sheet.getRange('G1:G13').getDisplayValues();
    var index = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < source.length; i++) {
      if (source[i][0] == "") {
        index.push(i + 1);
      }
    }
    index.push(range.getLastRow() + 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < index.length - 1; i++) {
      var rangetomodify = sheet.getRange(index[i], 7, 1, 1);
      rangetomodify.setFormulaR1C1("=R[0]C[4]");
    }
  }
  ```
- But, in this case, `getRange` and `setFormulaR1C1` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.

When your script is modified by reducing the process cost, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function updatewithformula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var source = sheet.getRange('G2:G13').getDisplayValues();
  var ranges = source.reduce((ar, [g], i) => {
    if (!g) ar.push(`G${i + 2}`);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setFormulaR1C1("=R[0]C[4]");
}
```

- By RangeList, the process cost can be reduced a little.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [setFormulaR1C1(formula) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setFormulaR1C1(String))

Answer (score 2):

There are better, easy and short methods to do it, I have used `offset` here.

The below works for me

```
function updatewithformula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange()
  var source = sheet.getRange('G1:G13').getValues();
  Logger.log(source);

  
  var index = [];
  for (var i in source){
    if(source[i][0] == ""){
      var j = +i;
      index.push(("G"+(j+1)));
    }
  }
 

  for (var i in index){
    var TEMP = sheet.getRange(index[i]);
    var TEMP1 = TEMP.offset(0,4).getA1Notation();
    const formula = `=${TEMP1}`;
    TEMP.setFormula(formula);

  }
}
```

References  - [OFFSET](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Comment: The legend and my inspiration @Tanaike -san has answered it perfectly